# Magento shipping_method progress block template override

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

How to override `shipping_mehtod.phtml` `file` in custom module
I override it but after shipping method selection in progress block data comes from **base** theme file not from my custom module file.

Below my code:

```
<reference name="shippingmethod.progress">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>module/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

Thankyou

Comment: Please show your codes. Without valid codes, we are unable to help you out.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy check this

Comment: we need your modules's config.xml file and location of your layout update xml file atleast.

Comment: Add your template file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below code in your layout file :

```
<checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="module/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>        
    </checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
```